# How can you set custom disclosure buttons for individual list items in Sencha?

Tags: sencha-touch

I've got an XTemplate set up to display different styles for different list items depending on what type they are. I also want to have different disclose buttons for each different type. I'm able to set all disclosure buttons to a custom image using:

```
.x-list-item .x-list-disclosure {
overflow: visible;
-webkit-mask: 0 0 url(path/to/image) no-repeat;
}
```

but I can't find a way to change individual disclosure buttons. I tried defining a custom class within the XTemplate ie:

```
var solutiontpl = new Ext.XTemplate (

            "</pre>",
            "<div class = 'solution-container'>",
                "<div class = 'list-item-title'>",
                    '<tpl if = "type == \'p\'">',
                    "{title}<span class = 'solution-rating-text'>{rating}</span>",
                    "<span class = 'partner-icon'></span>",
                    '</tpl>',
                    '<tpl if = "type == \'a\'">',
                    "{title}<span class = 'solution-rating-text'>{rating}</span>",
                    '</tpl>',
                    '<tpl if = "type == \'s\'">',
                    "{title}<span class = 'solution-rating-text'>{rating}</span>",
                    '</tpl>',
                "</div>",
            "</div>",
            "<pre>"
);
```

and tried using ".solution-container .x-list-item .x-list-disclosure" to set the disclosure button to no avail. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.solution-container .x-list-item .x-list-disclosure` won't work because the element with class `.solution-container` is actually the child of the element with the `.x-list-item` class.

Here is how the DOM looks like:

```
<div class="x-list-item ">
    <div class="x-list-item-body">
        <div class="solution-container">
        ....
        .... your itemTpl here
        ....
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="x-list-disclosure"></div>
</div>
```

To get it right, you should set an ID to the `Ext.List` configuration
(Sencha Touch 1.1):

```
var myList = new Ext.extend(Ext.List, {
    id: 'SpecialDisclosureList',
    store: MyStore,
    itemTpl: '<div> ... tpl ... </div>',
    onItemDisclosure: true
});
```

(Sencha Touch 2):

```
Ext.create('Ext.List', {
   id : 'SpecialDisclosureList',
   itemTpl: '<div> ... tpl ... </div>',
   store: MyStore
   onItemDisclosure: true
});
```

---

After setting an ID to the `Ext.List`, the following css styling will work:

```
#SpecialDisclosureList.x-list .x-list-disclosure {
    overflow: visible;
    -webkit-mask: 0 0 url(path/to/image) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This just change all the items' discloure icon, not setting different icons for different itmes